# ¿Por que no responde mi puerto serie cuando paso una variable string al arduino?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, arduino, pyserial

¿Por que no responde mi puerto serie cuando paso una variable string al arduino?

Estoy intentando pasar una variable string a mi arduino con python y serial.

He probado introducir la variable var con "input" y funciona perfectamente, pero si comento esa linea y pongo el mismo valor que pasaba en el input en una variable clasica no funciona.

¿Sabríais decirme que se me escapa?

```py
    import serial

    def test_serial():
       data_serial = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600)
       if data_serial.isOpen():
           #val = input("introduce color: ") #<-- this work :)
           val = 'r'                         #<-- this not :(
           data_serial.write(val.encode())

    test_serial()
```

Comment: Hola Jose, bienvenido a [es.so] ¿A que te refieres con que no responde?¿No envía nada?¿O da algún error?

Comment: El string 'r' cambia el color de una lampara. Cuando introduzco 'r' con input se pone la luz roja. Pero si pongo r como una variable.. no devuelve error ni nada... simplemente no reacciona, como si estuve dormido. :(

Comment: "r" de raro... XD En teoría `val` es lo mismo en ambos casos, `input` retorna un objeto `str` igual al que creas con el literal... De todas forma podemos cerciorarnos,  haz en el código que muestras justo antes del write: `val = "r"; val_in = input("introduce un valor: ");  print("literal: {}, input: {}, son iguales: {}".format(val.encode(), val_in.encode(), val.encode() == val_in.encode()))` ingresa tu "r" al `input` a ver que muestra y si cambia de color...

Comment: JAJAJAJ r = raro... lo has pillao a la primera :D. En principio lo he resuelto con un time.sleep,Me ha dado la sensacion de que necesita un espacio de tiempo entre los comando del arduino,, asi que he puesto ``` data_serial = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600) time.sleep(0.5) val = 'r'  ...``` y extrañamente funciona. Esta tarde probare lo que me comentas.

Comment: Solo era algo testimonial para que efectivamente comprobaras que el problema no estaba en la cadena. Lo que comentas es totalmente razonable, la única diferencia entre ambos casos es que `input` es bloqueante (igual que `sleep`), por lo que el tiempo entre la apertura del puerto y la escritura es mayor con `input` que con el literal de cadena. Claro que la comunicación serie no implementa nada para asegurar que la conexión está establecida, de todas formas no termino de entender este comportamiento , `open` retorna antes de que el puerto esté listo y `write` **falla silenciosamente**.

Comment: Mmmm acabo de encontrar quejas similares en el repo de github: https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial/issues/329#issuecomment-400852426